# Match where value is NULL in SPARQL

Tags: sql, sparql, allegrograph

I have the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?label ?img 
WHERE
{
  ?uri rdfs:label ?label .
  ?uri vtio:hasImage ?img .
}
```

With results like the following:

```
label | img
-------------
label | link1
labe2 | link2
…
```

I also want the label without `?img` also matched i.e. entries where `?img` is `NULL` i.e. I want results like the following:

```
label  | img
--------------
label1 | link1
label2 |
label3 | link3
…
```

If I use my earlier query a result for `label2` will not be shown?

How do I modify my query to also include rows like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use OPTIONAL:

```
select ?label ?img where {
?uri rdfs:label ?label.
 OPTIONAL { ?uri vtio:hasImage ?img. }
}
```

Comment: Broekstar :Thank you so much!